# Custom case distinctions in proofs

Tags: isabelle, isar

Does Isabelle support custom case distinctions when proving statements? Let's say I want to prove a statement for all natural numbers `n`, but the proof is entirely different depending on whether `n` is even or odd. Is it possible to do that case distinction in a proof, like

```
 proof(cases n) 
   assume "n mod 2 = 0"
   <proof>
   next assume "n mod 2 = 1"
   <proof>
qed
```

So far, I'd split the lemma/theorem in two seperate parts (assuming `n` even/odd) and then use these parts to proof the statement for all natural numbers, but that does not appear to be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Isabelle2017, you can prove ad-hoc case distinction rules easily, like so:

```
lemma "P (n::nat)"
proof -
  consider (odd) "odd n" | (even) "even n" by auto
  then show ?thesis
  proof cases
    case odd
    then show ?thesis sorry
  next
    case even
    then show ?thesis sorry
  qed
qed
```

Comment: While this is true (and has some advantages, e.g. being able to use `case`), `odd n` is just an abbreviation for `¬even n`, so one can just use the default case distinction rule: `have P proof cases assume "even n" … next assume "odd n" … qed`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try the following thing:

```
proof -
   have "your statement" when "n mod 2 = 0"
   <proof>
   moreover
   have "your statement" when "n mod 2 = 1"
   <proof>
   ultimately
   show "your statement"
     by <some tactic>
qed
```